# Understanding outputs in Playground

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6.1, swift-playground

Why does the following code outputs as follow in Playground...

```
class Vehicle{

    func run(){
        println("Running")//outputs--------- Running
    }
}

var jetta = Vehicle()// outputs ------------ Vehicle
jetta.run()// outputs ---------------------- Vehicle (why not running?)
```

Shouldn't the output for the last call be "Running"?

When I try the same code on [swiftstub.com](http://swiftstub.com) or [runswiftlang.com](http://www.runswiftlang.com) I get what I was expecting but not in Playground, why?

Output in [swiftstub.com](http://swiftstub.com) or [runswiftlang](http://www.runswiftlang.com)

```
class Vehicle{

    func run(){
        println("Running")//outputs--------- nothing
    }
}

var jetta = Vehicle()// outputs ------------ nothing
jetta.run()// outputs ---------------------- Running
```

Any idea why Playgound doesn't outputs Running when calling the method run()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right panel which is displayed by default in Xcode represents the result of each expression entered. In order to display the console output you need to open the assistant editor (alt+command+enter)

[image]